# Optimising neo4j cypher query for retrieving a social news feed

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher, feed

Up to to now I  have tried this query but it is really slow as scans all nodes. It is capable of what i want to retrieve

```
match (u:Users{user_id:140}),(p:Posts),(pu:Users{user_id:p.created_by}) optional match  (p)-[:POST_MEDIA]->(f) optional match (p)-[:COMMENT]->(c)<-[:COMMENT]-(u3)
where
(p)-[:CREATED_BY]->(u) or (p:PUBLIC and (u)-[:FOLLOW]->(pu) )or  (p:PRIVATE and (p)-[:SHARED_WITH]->(u))
return {user_id:pu.user_id,firstname:pu.firstname,lastname:pu.lastname,profile_photo:pu.profile_photo,username:pu.username} as pu,p,collect({user_id:u3.user_id,profile_photo:u3.profile_photo,text:c.text}) as comment,collect(f) as file order by p.post_id DESC  limit 25
```

Before this query i tried this query which is very fast but can't retrieve  complete news feed it is only capable of retrieving posts from followings only not users's himself and also not others users private posts which may be shared with the user that is retrieving newsfeed.

```
    match (u:Users{user_id:140})-[:FOLLOW]->(pu)<-[:CREATED_BY]-(p:Posts)
    optional match  (p)-[:POST_MEDIA]->(f)
    optional match (p)-[:COMMENT]->(c)<-[:COMMENT]-(u3) where p:PUBLIC     
    return
    {user_id:pu.user_id,firstname:pu.firstname,
   lastname:pu.lastname,profile_photo:pu.profile_photo,username:pu.username} as pu,p,
   collect({user_id:u3.user_id,profile_photo:u3.profile_photo,text:c.text}) as comment,
   collect(f) as file order by p.post_id DESC  limit 25
```

**Note:-**  By short of modifying in where clause like this:-

```
where p:PUBLIC or (p)-[:SHARED_WITH]->(u)
// but the only problem is that how i should include posts of users himself which is retrieving news feed .
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you should make sure you have an index on the `user_id` property for the `User` label.  Like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Users(user_id)
```

(incidentally it's common practice to use singular nouns for labels)

But you should also be using Neo4j relationships rather than matching from the post's `created_by` column.  That will allow Neo4j to traverse the relationship (which is very fast) compared to checking the index (which is still fast, but not as ideal, I think)

But you also have a problem, I think, with the fact that variables in a `WHERE` should be put in a `WHERE` clause directly after the `(OPTIONAL) MATCH` in question.  For example your `(p)-[:CREATED_BY]->(u)` condition refers to the variables defined in the first `MATCH`, but they are below the `OPTIONAL MATCH` and that `WHERE` will actually apply to the `OPTIONAL MATCH`.  You should be able to fix this by putting a `WITH *` in between, though you'd want to benchmark the performance.

Here is the query with some of those changes (not that you would need to setup the `CREATED` relationship separately first):

```
MATCH
  (u:Users {user_id:140}),
  (p:Posts)<-[:CREATED]-(pu:Users)
WHERE
  (p)-[:CREATED_BY]->(u) OR
  (p:PUBLIC AND (u)-[:FOLLOW]->(pu)) OR
  (p:PRIVATE AND (p)-[:SHARED_WITH]->(u))
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:POST_MEDIA]->(f)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:COMMENT]->(c)<-[:COMMENT]-(u3)
RETURN
  {user_id:pu.user_id,
    firstname:pu.firstname,
    lastname:pu.lastname,
    profile_photo:pu.profile_photo,
    username:pu.username} as pu,
  p,
  collect({user_id:u3.user_id,
           profile_photo:u3.profile_photo,
           text:c.text}) as comment,
  collect(f) as file
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC LIMIT 25
```

**EDIT**: Actually, looking at this, all of the variables in the `WHERE` are defined in that first `MATCH`, so you should be able to just move it up there.  Edited the query to reflect that.

**EDIT2**: You could try using `OPTIONAL MATCH` which, I think, would have Neo4j do the traversals first.  With the `WHERE` I think it's getting all possible results and then filtering, which wouldn't be as efficient.

```
PROFILE 
MATCH
  (u:Users {user_id:140}),
  (p:Posts)<-[:CREATED]-(pu:Users)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[created_by:CREATED_BY]->(u), (u)-[follow:FOLLOW]->(pu), (p)-[shared_with:SHARED_WITH]->(u)
WHERE created_by IS NOT NULL OR (p:PUBLIC AND follow IS NOT NULL) OR (p:PRIVATE AND shared_with IS NOT NULL)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:POST_MEDIA]->(f)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:COMMENT]->(c)<-[:COMMENT]-(u3)
RETURN
  {user_id:pu.user_id,
    firstname:pu.firstname,
    lastname:pu.lastname,
    profile_photo:pu.profile_photo,
    username:pu.username} as pu,
  p,
  collect({user_id:u3.user_id,
           profile_photo:u3.profile_photo,
           text:c.text}) as comment,
  collect(f) as file
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC LIMIT 25
```

You also might want to experiment with an indexed property to indicate `private` rather than using labels.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, try sharing a `PROFILE` of the query

Comment: yes i have allready an index on user_id,post_id and other id related fields

Comment: ok have an nice experience with sql thats why i reached to this much level of cql  but in real i have just 10 days experience of neo4j and do you meaning  ` time taken by query ` by PROFILE

Comment: but bro your code snippet will scan all nodes...   than whats the use of my relationships created like      :SHARED_WITH can you suggest me a way so  that i use shared_with relationship directly in match so that it gives superfast results and retrive public posts separately    btw   +1

Comment: If you put `PROFILE ` before your query it will output information about how Neo4j went about executing your query and where the slow points are.  http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html

Comment: I'm using `SHARED_WITH` in the query, am I not?  It's just moved up to go with the first `MATCH` clause because otherwise I think it will be ignored

Comment: yes bro , but this solution is correct upto when nodes are less than lakhs but when there will be nodes in lakhs it will really be a big pain to me as well as server  i accept that my above code was also some errors and you solved them but the main problem is that it scans all nodes i checked that in profile and plz tell how i provide you the profile

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand (what is lakhs?), but you can profile any query by putting `PROFILE ` in front like this: `PROFILE MATCH n RETURN n`

Comment: in india 100 thousand=1lakh   btw this is profile of your code snipet view this svg https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6eYtQWzwONUR09tbnYtUGpqeUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: yes first code   is better and you have made a short mistake in second edit may be i am wrong  ..mistake is in optional match of 2nd edit . Why you are checking that u follow pu or not as u itself created the post

Comment: I was just going from your query.  Your `WHERE` clause has a `(u)-[:FOLLOW]->(pu)`

Comment: yes that is because I mistaken one thing i was having two question one how to  optimise and other how to find post of friends + post of user itself  , but i set title of question only for first question , and the  `(u)-[:FOLLOW]->(pu)` is used to check that does user even follow post creater or  not as query was written only for getting posts of followings or friends only

Answer (score 0):

you should use Match(c) match (p:Posts) I mean use multiple matches.
Also you should use constraints on User user_id.

You should not use ()-[]->() inside where clauses. Maybe you could use optional Match.

You should also profile your query to see how it behaves. So you can reduce your db hits.

Comment: would you elaborate what you are saying plz give a short snippet

Comment: There are plenty of scenarios where you'd want to specify a pattern in a WHERE clause.